# Google Sheets API | IP Problem

Tags: javascript, api, google-spreadsheet, ip, google-apps-script

Пытаюсь сделать функцию связанную с Clash Royale API, для этого мне нужно использовать собственно созданный токен под свой или определенный IP. Так я не знаю если могу обратится сюда с данной проблемой, но все же. В самой функции все должно работать, но вот сам APPS Script делает какую-ту непонятную ерезь. А именно каждый раз когда нажимаю на (ВЫПОЛНИТЬ), он ставит условие под новым IP, непонятно мне почему и как это происходит.

[Вот тут пример на YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GW8KZlyVk3E&ab_channel=Google%2CNo-LowCodeApps%26MindsetTransformation%21)

Вот функция:

```
function getClashRoyalePlayerInfo() {
  var apiKey = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsImtpZCI6IjI4YTMxOGY3LTAwMDAtYTFlYi03ZmExLTJjNzQzM2M2Y2NhNSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBlcmNlbGwiLCJhdWQiOiJzdXBlcmNlbGw6Z2FtZWFwaSIsImp0aSI6IjEyYTMzYTk4LTNmMzQtNDg3OS04OGM5LTI5NTA1MGVjNmQxZSIsImlhdCI6MTcwNzU0Njg4Nywic3ViIjoiZGV2ZWxvcGVyL2IwMTdlMjAwLTMxZDctMDU0MC01YzI5LTg5Y2YwZDc2NjcwZSIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJyb3lhbGUiXSwibGltaXRzIjpbeyJ0aWVyIjoiZGV2ZWxvcGVyL3NpbHZlciIsInR5cGUiOiJ0aHJvdHRsaW5nIn0seyJjaWRycyI6WyI3NS4yMDMuNTQuMjUyIiwiMTA3LjE3OC4yMDMuMTAwIiwiMzUuMTg3LjEzMi43IiwiMTA3LjE3OC4yMDMuMTAzIiwiMzQuMTE2LjIyLjgxIl0sInR5cGUiOiJjbGllbnQifV19.ZTevnqvTKCrhP7zrkgOSdA_w9Xy0n9E1AiPhEb-iRQiu7shN0QCbWWyPfPdeRGUJ7y25ZDYnWQoWr7kyW4I2_Q"; // Ваш ключ API Clash Royale
  
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey
  };

  var playerTag = encodeURIComponent("#PGGUCQLP0"); // Кодируем тэг игрока для использования в URL

  var url = "https://api.clashroyale.com/v1/players/" + playerTag;

  var options = {
    "method": "GET",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": headers
  };

  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    
    // Выводим полученные данные в журнал
    Logger.log(data);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log("Ошибка при запросе к API Clash Royale: " + e);
  }
}
```

Вот ошибка которая мне вылезает, только с каждым разом APPS script выдает новый IP:

```
01:52:24    Примечание  Выполнение начато
01:52:27    Информация  Invalid authorization: API key does not allow access from IP 34.116.22.65
01:52:24    Примечание  Выполнение завершено
```

Если кто-то сталкивался с данной проблемой и нашел решение, пожалуйста поделитесь. Спасибо.

Comment: короче, в итоге я поковырял несколько форумов, там все говорят что у Apps Script есть целый список своих IP адресов, и сделать статический тупо невозможно. Тупо но ладно.